# Alternative to pass @ in curl parameter value

Tags: php, post, curl

I'm using curl library to connect with an api.
I'm having this weird problem, one of the parameters, specifically the user's password starts with "@", and because of this curls fails:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50060

Do I have an alternative to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS for passing this parameter?

Thanks

Comment: nope. if you want to start a field's value with a `@`, you have to build the whole query string yourself. There's no way to tell PHP that you're **NOT** trying to attach a file to the POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up changing

```
$postData => array(...)
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData
```

For

```
$postData => array(...)
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($postData)
```